# SSL problem when making requests in threaded gunicorn app

Tags: python, python-requests, thread-safety, gunicorn, urllib3

I have a python app hosted in APP engine with the gunicorn gthread worker:
`gunicorn -w 4 --threads 16 src.main:app`

In my app i make requests to a GCP cloud function in this way:

`response = requests.post(url, json=payload)`

I have bugsnag as error reporting and i keep getting the following error:
`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='GCP CLOUD FUNCTION', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /path (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)')))`

[image: Bugsnag error]

I'm using python 3.11 with `requests 2.28.2` `urllib3 1.26.15`
How can i avoid this problem in a threaded gunicorn app?

At first i thought it was a problem with certificates, i tried setting `verify=False` in the requests.post call, and the error stopped, however the problem also occurs in other libraries i use, like bugsnag and google cloud storage, and i can't disable that parameter there.

Maybe i was calling the functions too much, i reduced calls per minute of my app, but it kept occurring.

Tried updating python and dependiencies, it also failed.

Then i tried a last approach, removing `--threads` from the gunicorn entrypoint, and then the error was gone.

Does python requests work in a multi threaded environment? I searched around and found it was, as long as i don't reuse a requests.Session in many threads, but that's not the case, unless... requests uses a global session under the hood?

Comment: Where are you storing the SSL certificate?

Comment: I didn't configure any specific ssl certificate. I hoped that the system trusts google certificates.

Comment: It could be an error due the google ssl certificate.
Are you able to reproduce the issue with a self signed certificate locally?